# Can somebody explain this tricky sql?

Tags: sql

what would the below sql return and why?

```
SELECT 1 + '+' + 2
```

Comment: In most databases it returns an error

Comment: Please tag your question with the particular flavor of SQL you are using.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com - what do *you* get, and in which databases?

Comment: both sql server and mysql returns 3. thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same reason `SELECT 1 + 'whocares' + 2` results in 3. In some database systems, 'strings' evaluate to 0 if they can't be interpreted as a number. Try `SELECT 1 + '2' + 3` to see an example of where it CAN be interpreted as a number.

And yes, the "in some database systems" applies to this whole answer, where I'm going to guess you're using something like MySQL.

Comment: @andrewwowens also makes a valid point in his answer below that this only works when the evaluation is in a numeric sense rather than a string concatenation sense - and this is basically determined by whether a number or a string comes first.

Answer (score 2):

One way of thinking about this type of mathematical logic is that SQL manages your math functions in a given order of operation.

```
SELECT 1 + 'whocares' + 2
-- Results in a number as the first item processed, 1, tells SQL it is about to deal with integers
SELECT 'whocares' + 1 + '...this guy'
-- Results in a string of 'whocares...this guy' as the first item is a string
```

Actually, the second line may fail depending on which SQL syntax/system you're using... but you get the point.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to check this logic based on the SQL syntax you work in. For instance, neither of the above work in the Impala SQL syntax as Impala uses string and mathematical functions to manage this kind of concatenation or addition.